# Program trying to load the cs.html file, giving a 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting a HTTP 404.
I don't know what I did that suddenly started causing this error. I changed the startpage, then it began reporting this error.
I have found the file `RouteConfig.cs` (guessing this is where the solution might be) which looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Member", action = "AddMember", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The error I am getting says that the ressource could not be found, reports this URL:

```
http://localhost:53043/Views/Member/AddMember.cshtml
```

I noticed that it suddenly want's to look for the `.cshtml` file. But isn't this wrong?

The controller to the `AddMember` View looks like this:

```
public ActionResult AddMember()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If I rightclick on the AddMember.cshtml file, and choose `View in browser`, then the page show up just fine, and the URL looks like this `http://localhost:53043/Member/AddMember`

Any idea to how I can solve this pls?

Comment: What you see is the expected behavior. You do not access the cshtml file directly, but you access it via action method. I suggest you refresh the basics of MVC.

Comment: I am very new to asp.net mvc. What does it mean when you say "Refresh the basics of MVC"?

Comment: Learn how mvc routing works.

Comment: Views must stay inside the `View` directory inside your project. Move your `AddMember.cshtml` to `Views/Member/AddMember.cshtml`.

Comment: It's already in there. I create views in the Views dir

Answer (score 1):

> If I rightclick on the AddMember.cshtml file, and choose View in browser, then the page show up just fine, and the URL looks like this http://localhost:53043/Member/AddMember

The expected url for any cshtml page (or ActionResult of a controller) in MVC C# is `http://localhost:{port}/{controller}/{action}/{id}` where id is optional as stated in the route config.

The way you're trying to view the page `http://localhost:{port}/Views/{controller}/{action}.cshtml` is the file directory of the view and not the way to view a cshtml file in the browser.

To view a result of any cshtml file, simply press `F5`, `Ctrl + F5`, or right click and view in browser, they all return same result. Good luck.

Comment: The error comes when I press F5 in VS.
I am having a hard time finding out what the "Set as startpage" is good for, if it sets the MapRoute to point to the .cshtml, which seems to be giving a wrong result. I have tried to follow the convention, and placed my new View in the already existing folder called Views. But thanks for your help/words anyway :-)

Comment: Your routeconfig file looks fine. Try some other files, maybe Global.asax or Startup.cs. Off the top of my head, I don't remember exactly, but one of those files should have the settings. Also try your AppStart folder that might have a file holding those settings.

Comment: I solved it by rightclicking on my projectname -> Properties -> Web, and then under Start Action, there is a place saying "Specific page". Here it said: Views/Member/AddMember.cshtml, so instead, I hardcoded it to: Member/AddMember. Then it works fine when I press F5, and doesn't report the 404 anymore. But something just tells me that this shouldn't be the way to do it. I'm worry it might give me problems later

Comment: You may be able to select some other option (other than "Specific page") instead of having to hard code that. I think there's an option for "Current page" or something along that line.

Answer (score -1):

The URL is wrong , you cannot directly load the ".cshtml" file. In MVC , you need to call the controller method which then calls the view. If your controller name is  "Member"  and method name is "AddMember" then the URL should be listed as mentioned below. Hope This Helps!

http://localhost:53043/Views/Member/AddMember.cshtml